# Light cutoff alarm circuit PNP output

Tags: pnp, phototransistor

The purpose was to check the voltage on the PNP tr collector side. So when we cut off the light, we expected about 12V. When we detected light, we expected it to be printed around 1.6V. I checked the output with the oscilloscope, and it output 9 to 10 volts both when light was detected and when it was blocked. I think the reason why it went down from 12V to 9V is because it has LED and BUZZER in between.

[image]

So we moved the load end to the emitter and measured the emitter voltage. When the light was cut off, it was 1.6V. When it was detected, it was 10V.

[image]

The question is:

I want to know why the collector cuts off the light when it's measured, but it outputs without changing to 9V, and if it's toward the emitter, does it change and how it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the LM358 is that it can't output a potential equal to its positive supply, +12V in your case. The highest it can output is something like 1V or 1.5V *less than* that, say +10.5V. That means it cannot ever switch  *off* your PNP transistor. To switch the transistor off completely would require the op-amp to output *at least* \$(+12V) - V_{BE} = +11.3V\$.

It is perfectly able to get its output very close to the negative supply, to within a few tens of millivolts, in fact. Therefore it would work well if the transistor was NPN:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKCZyr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By placing the load at the emitter, all you have done is implement an "[emitter follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector)", in which (surprise) emitter potential follows base potential, just \$V_{BE}\$ higher. This explains why the load always experiences a voltage across it just slightly different (0.7V different) from the op-amp output (which don't forget is unable to get higher than about +10.5V).

You have a few options. The first I alluded to above; use an NPN transistor. The second solution would be to use an op-amp that *is* able to get its output all the way up to the positive supply, such as the [TLV271](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv271.pdf). Such devices are labelled as "rail-to-rail output".

Lastly (there are many solutions, but this is the last one I will suggest), you can offset the op-amp output using a zener diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9SIsQ.png)</sup>

This simply adds about 3.6V to the op-amp's output, so that it is able to reach the +12V base potential necessary to switch off Q1.